# Oracle: Store date in a BLOB field and retrieve as date when needed

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, blob, clob

I am using this expression to store a date directly in a BLOB field:

```
utl_raw.cast_to_raw(sysdate)
```

This works fine, but when I need to retrieve this date, I can't manage to retrieve the time as well, only the date, with the function below.

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(sysdate))
```

Is there a way to retrieve the date I stored **with time**?

PS: I know I can just convert the date to a varchar with TO_CHAR and datetime format before storing it, but let's assume I can't do it right now.

Comment: Using VARCHAR2 is as bad as using BLOB. Why on earth not using DATE?

Comment: Date values should be stored in `DATE` columns. Everything else is  begging for trouble.

Comment: It's an audit table and "old" and "new" columns are blob to simple accept anything. That's the reason I'm using BLOB fields. Any other suggestions to create a generic audit table?

Comment: don't go for generic, use the proper data types as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`utl_raw.cast_to_raw`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-E837A246-2D2A-47C4-A2F3-29735F596CE1) accepts a string, not a date, therefore what you are capturing is effectively `to_char(sysdate)`. This will use the current `nls_date_format` which is typically something like `DD-MON-RRRR` (and `nls_date_language` which might be English but could vary depending on user desktop settings). You'll need to either change the default or specify a different format, e.g.

```
utl_raw.cast_to_raw(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```